# Vue.js при обычной верстке

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Я пишу код и верстаю недавно, скорее даже только учусь. Мне приглянулся Vue.JS, немного пишу на нем. Суть вопроса, нормально ли использовать подобные фреймворки при верстке обычных сайтов, например таких как лендинги ну или что то не очень сложное. Там где минимум js кода, а если прям совсем извертеться можно и вовсе наверное без него обойтись. Как вообще принято? Закрадываются мысли, что с точки зрения для понимания других верстальщиков лучше обходиться без подобных фреймворков, но хочется писать на нем даже если это простые элементы

Comment: Хотите - пишите, вас никто не ущемляет

Comment: Я не спрашивал об ущемлениях, вопрос в другом.

Comment: Для чего другим верстальщикам понимать? Полагаю, чтобы дорабатывать. Тогда договаривайтесь с командой. Работаете без команды? Тогда ваше личное дело. А навык VueJS делает вас из рядового верстальщика фронендером :)

Comment: тут скорее вопрос рациональности, в примере с лендосом вполне справится jquery, а вот когда вы уже понимаете, что на vue будет быстрее и проще, то лучше использовать его, опять же повторюсь с jquery на мелких задачах меньше времени уйдет

Comment: В данном случае при верстке полноценного лендинга вам необходимо использовать `VueJS` из-за компонентности и подключаемости модулей.

Answer (score 1):

Верстать лендинги на Vue - это "нормально" и хорошо!

Догадываюсь что верстка под VueJS или React будет проходить немного по другому. Ведь в обеих используются так называемые "компоненты". В итоге даже одна лендинг страница будет разбита на множество компонентов. Есть также подход когда "компонент" независимый.

Хотелось бы чтобы более профессиональные коллеги тут более подробно описали основные подходы.

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» ваш ответ или вопрос